# How to disable one of two Angular animations on the same element?

Tags: angular, animation

I have an Angular 6 menu component with two animations :

- Slide up / slide down (for certain screen sizes or pages it is hidden)
- Fade in / fade out (when I activate a slide in menu from the side)

In other words there are two animations on the same element `[@menuSlideAnimation]` `[@menuFadeAnimation]`

If I add `[@.disabled]="true"` to the element then it disables both. If I add an extra `<div>` into the equation I can put `[@.disabled]="false"` to the child element - but this is both klunky, difficult to follow and adds all kinds of complexity when dealing with static / sticky positioning.

I am currently *not* using [`AnimationBuilder`](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationBuilde) to create the transitions, so as I understand it everything is compiled away and I can't just access an 'instance' of an animation.

How can I disable one animation by name?

Answer (score 2):

Define two identical `open` states called `'open'` and `'open-instant'`. Give them the same exact state.

To prevent animation from happening I trigger the `open-instant` state, which has no defined transitions. When I want animation I trigger the `open` state which has a defined `closed => open` state.

```
   trigger('menuAnimation',
    [
        state('closed', style({
            'transform': 'translate(0, -100%)'
        })),

        state('open', style({
            'transform': 'translate(0, 0%)',
        })),

        state('open-instant', style({
            'transform': 'translate(0, 0%)',
        })),

        // transitions are not triggered for state 'open-instant'
        transition('open => closed', [
            animate('300ms ease-in-out')
        ]),

        transition('closed => open', [
            animate('500ms ease-in-out')
        ])
    ]),
```

The animation is applied to my host component (this is the `menu-bar.component` file).

```
@HostBinding('@menuSlideAnimation') get menuSlideAnimation() {
    return (this.showMenu ? 'open' : 'closed') + 
           (this.disableSlideAnimation ? '-instant' : '');
}
```

Then `showMenu` and `disableSlideAnimation` are just booleans.